# Enable MySQL event_scheduler on XAMPP

Tags: mysql, events, phpmyadmin, xampp

When I type in phpmyadmin the sql command: **SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;**

the event_scheduler process is running, but when I restart the server - it stops.

I've tried editing the my.ini file to:

```
[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates
event_scheduler=ON
```

but it didn't work.
please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if anyone is interested, the problem was the header:
[mysqld] instead of [mysql]